# Php in EJS is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, ejs

Php in EJS is it possible?

I want to know if its possible to make php code in ejs?
I only need this 3 code lines.`<br>`

```
password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);<br>
password_verify($pass, $hashpruef)<br>
password_needs_rehash<br>
```

Comment: The answer is no.